# Problems replacing character values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

One of my column in my datafra looks like this:

```
[1] "MIT"  "MIT"  "NUC"  "MIT"  "CYT"  "MIT"  "NUC"  "MIT"  "CYT"  "NUC"  "NUC"  "CYT"  "MIT"  "MIT"  ""     ""     "CYT" 

[18] "NUC"  "NUC"  "NUC"  "CYT"  "CYT"  "CYT"  "CYT"  "CYT"  "MIT"  "CYT"  "CYT"  "MIT"  "ME1"  "NUC"  "MIT"  "CYT"  "NUC" 

[35] "ME1"  "EXC"  "MIT"  "CYT"  "MIT"  "MIT"  "ME2"  "ME2"  ""     ""     "ME3"  "VAC"  "NUC"  "ME2"  "EXC"  "VAC"  "ME3"
```

I need to change "ME3" for ME.

When I used this code:

```
df_norm_pre$MIT["ME1"]="ME"
```

I find this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, MIT, value = c("MIT", "MIT", "NUC",
>   : replacement has 1550 rows, data has 1549.

Could someone help me with this problems?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
df_norm_pre$MIT <- replace(df_norm_pre$MIT, df_norm_pre$MIT == "ME3", "ME")
```

Or just assignment

```
df_norm_pre$MIT[df_norm_pre$MIT == "ME3"] <- "ME"
```

Or with `sub`

```
df_norm_pre$MIT <-  sub("^ME\\d+$", "ME", df_norm_pre$MIT)
```

---

Error in OP's code is because the indexing is not correct

```
df_norm_pre$MIT["ME1"]
```

The `df_norm_pre$MIT` extracts the column as a `vector`, then using `["ME1"]`, expects that is either a column with name of "ME1" or a `list` with that name.  Both of these are not TRUE here.  Instead, we can use logical index to subset `df_norm_pre$MIT == "ME1"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `gsub` to see if it can do the replacement

```
df_norm_pre <- within(df_norm_pre, MIT <- gsub("ME3","ME",MIT))
```

or use `replace` like

```
df_norm_pre <- within(df_norm_pre, MIT <- replace(MIT, MIT == "ME3", "ME"))
```

Comment: @akrun now I changed my answer a bit to increase the diversity besides your solutions :)